Product and reciprocals of infinite products in the case of normal and absolute convergence.
This is a proposition I formulated although it may already exist. I saw the usage of it in other proofs like the divergence of the reciprocals of the primes and I wanted to prove this proposition just for fun.

Proposition. Given a sequence of complex numbers $a_n$ and $b_n$ that are not equal to zero. If
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=A, \quad \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n=B
$$
which means in particular that both products are convergent, then
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{-1}=A^{-1}, \quad \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_n b_n\right)=AB.
$$
The same applies if convergence is replaced by absolute convergence (not sure).

Proof. Because of logarithm rules, which hold, as $\log 1= 0$ and $\log a_n$ exists (Theorem 1), the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log \frac{1}{a_n}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log a_n, \qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log a_nb_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\log a_n+\log b_n\right)
$$
and the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \log a_n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \log b_n$ converge according to Theorem 1 if and only if the products $A$ and $B$ do, which shows the convergence. Now as
$$
\lim \frac{1}{a_n}= \frac{1}{\lim a_n}, \qquad \lim a_nb_n=\lim a_n \lim b_n,
$$
the two formulas follow.
Statements I used:

Theorem 1. Let $\log$ be a branch of the logarithm such that $\log 1=0$ and that $\log a_{n}$ is defined for all $n$. The infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ is convergent if and only if the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log a_{n} \tag{1}
$$
is convergent. In this case, the following applies
$$
    \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}=\exp \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log a_{n}.
$$
The series in $(1)$ is absolutely convergent if and only if the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{n}-1\right) \tag{2}
$$
is absolutely convergent.


Theorem 2. The product in Theorem 1 is called absolutely convergent if the series $(2)$ is absolutely convergent. An infinite product is absolutely convergent if every rearrangement converges to the same value.


My questions: I wanted to know if my proof is correct in the case of normal convergence. Now I do not know how to show it for the absolute convergence. I think one has to use the comparison test like
$$
\left|\frac{1}{a_n}-1\right|=\left|\frac{1-a_n}{a_n}\right| \leq 2 |a_n-1| \leq 1
$$
and
$$
\left|a_n b_n-1\right| \leq\left|a_n-1\right|\left|b_n-1\right|+\left|a_n-1\right|+\left|b_n-1\right|.
$$
But I fail to show the rest and that the formulas hold. Thanks for any hints, sorry for the long post, I wanted to show all my effort.

$A=\prod a_n$ can be $0$ even if $a_n \ne 0$ for all $n$.  [Ex: $a_n=\frac1  2$ for all $n$].

Logarithm rules you have used do not apply to complex numbers.

@geetha290krm Here because of Thm 1, the logarithm is a branch so that $\log 1=0$ and $\log a_n$ is defined for all $a_n$. Then the rules do apply.

@geetha290krm In your case one says „the infinite product diverges to $0$“.

These infinite products are defined in terms of limits of their finite partial products, and on the level of partial products these statements are obvious; so the result follows immediately from the continuity of reciprocals and multiplication. No need for logarithms even (not that that's a bad instinct).
